# set Volume level while mixing audios

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using below code to mix audios

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=src/bg.mp3:loop=999[s];[0][s]amix=duration=shortest out.mp3';
```

I want to set audio.mp3 volume to 75% and bg.mp3 to 50% , how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the simple [volume filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume):

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=src/bg.mp3:loop=999,volume=0.5[s];[0]volume=0.75[t];[s][t]amix=duration=shortest" out.mp3';
```

Comment: hi , can you give me any tutorial to learn about filter_complex  , I really dont understand [0]  , [0:a]  etc... I searched alot but no basic tutorials.

Comment: what is [s] and what is [t]

Comment: @Vishnu The `[s]` and `[t]` are examples of labels to give a name for each filter output so it can be referenced by other filters or output. Name them whatever you want. The `[s]` came from your command so I arbitrarily used `[t]` for the next volume filter instance. As for input labels, `[0]` refers to the first input `audio.mp3`. See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Description), [filtering examples in the wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide), and of course you can search the thousands of [tag:ffmpeg] questions here on Stack Overflow.